# Update the MessageBoxText runtime using System.Windows.MessageBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I'm using `System.Windows.MessageBox` to show the message to user, But I want to update the text on that `Messagebox`, after showing it.

The example in my case, I want to show the `MessageBox` with the content that can change at runtime as below:

```
"The system will be restarted in 5 seconds"
"The system will be restarted in 4 seconds"
"The system will be restarted in 3 seconds"
"The system will be restarted in 2 seconds"
"The system will be restarted in 1 second"
"The system will be restarted in 0 second"
```

Someone can show me how to do it?

Many thanks,

T&T

Comment: Minor nitpick: it should be `0 seconds`

Comment: check this out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box this probably shows what you need

Comment: My goodness that "Custom Message Box" project is ugly! [Use a `TaskDialog` instead](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17026/TaskDialog-for-WinForms). (Also available as part of the [Windows API Code Pack for .NET](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), along with a lot of other great stuff.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be possible with [`MessageBox`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox&referringTitle=Home) from Extended WPF Toolkit.
It has `Text` dependency property, which can be data bound, but, unfortunately, `MessageBox` initialization is hidden, and solution contains more than single line:

First of all, we need our `MessageBox` ancestor, because we're going to call protected `InitializeMessageBox` method (to apply standard message box settings). Then, we need to  make our `Show` overload, which will apply binding to `Text`:

```
class MyMessageBox : Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox
{
    public static MessageBoxResult Show(object dataContext)
    {
        var messageBox = new MyMessageBox();

        messageBox.InitializeMessageBox(null, null, "Hello", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Cancel);
        messageBox.SetBinding(MyMessageBox.TextProperty, new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
            Source = dataContext
        });
        messageBox.ShowDialog();
        return messageBox.MessageBoxResult;
    }
}
```

Next, we need a data context:

```
sealed class MyDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (text != value)
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }
    private string text;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And a code, which will change the text in message box:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MyDataContext dataContext;
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer;
    private int secondsElapsed;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataContext = new MyDataContext();
        timer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, 
            TimerElapsed, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        secondsElapsed = 0;
        timer.Start();

        MyMessageBox.Show(dataContext);

        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataContext.Text = string.Format("Elapsed {0} seconds.", secondsElapsed++);
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't need to write yet another message box.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's easier to use another window instead of `MessageBox`. Then you turn off features that you don't want (resizing, close button), make it modal, set up timer event handling, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

> Someone can show me how to do it

You can't do it with standard messagebox i.e. `System.Windows.MessageBox`.

**Alternative**:

Though what you can do is to define a `custom message box`(a windows form) with a `label` on it that you update via event `asynchronously`. And you use that to display user the count down.